# Extract route paramers from route string to use them as parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Suppose, I have these Angular routes :

```
const routes = {
  foo: '/foo/:paramFoo',
  bar: '/bar/:paramFoo/:paramBar',
  baz: '/baz/baz2/:paramFoo/:paramBar',
} as const;
```

I'd like to extract the parameters of theses routes, to pass them as paramter to a function like following :

```
routing(routes.foo) // should suggest (route: "/foo/:paramFoo", paramFoo: string)
routing(routes.bar) // should suggest (route: "/foo/:paramFoo", paramFoo: string, paramBar: string)
```

I came up with following :

```
const routes = {
  foo: '/foo/:paramFoo',
  bar: '/bar/:paramFoo/:paramBar',
  baz: '/baz/baz2/:paramFoo/:paramBar',
} as const;

type Routes = typeof routes;

type RouteParser<S extends string> =
  string extends S ? string[] :
  S extends '' ? [] :
  S extends `${infer T}/:${infer U}` ? [T, ...RouteParser<U>] : [S];

type RouteParams<S extends Array<string>> = S extends [infer path, ...infer params] ? params : [];

function routing<T extends keyof Routes>(route: Routes[T], ...params: RouteParams<RouteParser<Routes[T]>>) {

}
```

I'm pretty close but can't wrap my head to arround to achieve the expected result.

Also how can I include the `RouteParser` part with the `RouteParams`?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Looks like you already got it. What's missing?

Comment: You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx3JXN), but you cannot name the parameters correctly. Dynamically named tuple elements aren't possible yet, but dynamically named object keys are.

Comment: @TobiasS. Nah, look carefully, I have `params_0: "paramFoo"` but i want `param_0: string`. Like I said, pretty close !

Comment: @kelly A dynamically named object could actually be acceptable !

Comment: That would look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQxJAW).

Comment: @kelly thanks ever so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @kelly help, I came up with this following version :

```
const routes = {
  foo: '/foo/:paramFoo',
  bar: '/bar/:paramFoo/:paramBar',
  baz: '/baz/baz2/:paramFoo/:paramBar',
} as const;

type Routes = typeof routes;

type RouteParser<S extends string> =
  string extends S ? string[] :
  S extends '' ? [] :
  S extends `${infer T}/:${infer U}` ? [T, ...RouteParser<U>] : [S];

  type RouteParams<S extends string> = RouteParser<S> extends [infer path, ...infer params extends string[]] ? {
    [K in params[number]]: string;
  } : [];


function navigateTo<T extends keyof Routes, U extends Routes[T]>(route: U, params: RouteParams<U>) {
  let actualRoute: string = route;
  Object.keys(params).forEach((param) => {
    actualRoute = actualRoute.replace(`:${param}`, params[param]);
  })    
}


navigateTo(routes.foo, { paramFoo: 'foo' })
navigateTo(routes.bar, { paramFoo: 'foo', paramBar: 'bar' })
navigateTo(routes.baz, { paramFoo: 'foo', paramBar: 'bar' })
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-routing-params?file=index.ts,)